# Reasonable way to know when call function GPS/XML Android

Tags: android, xml, time, gps, sequence

I have 2 functions:

1) GetLocation which gives me coordinates.

2) Create and write this coordinates to xml file (XmlCreateWrite).

And here we are. As we know getting coordinates takes some time (we don't know exactly how much because it depends from our location, device etc.) so how this second function should know that's the time for her(I mean I want call function "XmlCreateWrite" when I already have coordinates but I don't know when it is ). What should I do. I have an idea to froze it on 1 min for example but there is an option that getting coordinates takes more time and I get empty xml file(additionally I don't think that is reasonable way).

Comment: paste some code where you're stuck.

Comment: there's nothing to paste just in OnCreate i call first GetLocation, then XmlCreateWrite but XmlCreateWrite start before GetLocation get coordinates that's all. I don't even know where I should looking for solution